# Map Dataframe to Dictionary and lookup values from other cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm finding the relationships between products that I sell on my shop.
I have this dictionary with the bundles of products that shopper happens to buy together with oduct IDs and no of sales (that those products were brought together)

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ('Product1', 'Product2') | 12 |
| ('Product2', 'Product4') | 7 |
| ('Product3', 'Product1','Product5') | 6 |
| ('Product5') | 4 |

I also have a data frame with the product & product name (I'm not sure if I need a dataframe here, can convert it to a Dictionary if need to)

| Product ID | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Name 1 |
| Product 2 | Name 2 |
| Product 3 | Name 3 |
| Product 4 | Name 4 |

Can some one please recommend me the best approach to use Product ID to lookup Product Name from the dataframe so I can build something like this

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| (Product 1, Name 1), (Product 2, Name 2) | 12 |
| (Product 2, Name 2), (Product 4, Name 4) | 7 |
| (Product 3, Name 3), (Product 1, Name 1), (Product 5, Name 5) | 6 |

I am new in python, I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509506/map-dataframe-to-dictionary-and-lookup-values-from-other-cells/68511114#68511114)! And reply if that is what you want. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created my own dataset and tested, Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"Product ID":["123","234","345"],"Product Name":["aa","bb","cc"]})
dff=pd.DataFrame({"Key":[("123","345"),("345","123","234"),("123","234")],"Value":["12","3","4"]})

print(df)
print(dff)

df.set_index("Product ID",inplace=True)
dc=df.to_dict()["Product Name"]

for i,row in enumerate(dff["Key"]):dff["Key"][i]=[(x,dc[x]) for x in row]

print(dff)
```

Output :

```
df:
  Product ID Product Name
0        123           aa
1        234           bb
2        345           cc

dff:
               Key   Value
0       (123, 345)    12
1  (345, 123, 234)     3
2       (123, 234)     4

Last dff:
                                 Key   Value
0             [(123, aa), (345, cc)]    12
1  [(345, cc), (123, aa), (234, bb)]     3
2             [(123, aa), (234, bb)]     4
```

And I have tested on @Pierre D reproducible setup data, here's the code of that:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product ID': [f'Product{i}' for i in range(6)],'Product Name': [f'Name {i}' for i in range(6)],})
dff = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [('Product1', 'Product2'),('Product2', 'Product4'),('Product3', 'Product1', 'Product5'),('Product5',)], 'Value': [12, 7, 6, 4]})

print(df)
print(dff)

df.set_index("Product ID",inplace=True)
dc=df.to_dict()["Product Name"]

for i,row in enumerate(dff["Key"]):dff["Key"][i]=[(x,dc[x]) for x in row]

print(dff)
```

Output :

```
df:
  Product ID Product Name
0   Product0       Name 0
1   Product1       Name 1
2   Product2       Name 2
3   Product3       Name 3
4   Product4       Name 4
5   Product5       Name 5

dff:
                              Key  Value
0            (Product1, Product2)     12
1            (Product2, Product4)      7
2  (Product3, Product1, Product5)      6
3                     (Product5,)      4

last dff:
                                                 Key  Value
0           [(Product1, Name 1), (Product2, Name 2)]     12
1           [(Product2, Name 2), (Product4, Name 4)]      7
2  [(Product3, Name 3), (Product1, Name 1), (Prod...      6
3                               [(Product5, Name 5)]      4
```

**Explanation:**

```
df.set_index("Product ID",inplace=True)
dc=df.to_dict()["Product Name"]
```

Here we are doing:

1. Setting `Product Id` as index,
2. And change that dataframe into dictionary(`dc`). So, that we can replace `Product Name` with `Product Id`.

```
for i,row in enumerate(dff["Key"]):dff["Key"][i]=[(x,dc[x]) for x in row]
```

And here we are doing:

1. Changing `(Product1, Product2)` value to `[(Product1, Name 1), (Product2, Name 2)]` by iterating all over `Key` column and making new `list of tuple` by using that dictionary(`dc`).

Comment: I don't really know that this is the best solution but its my best try.

Comment: thanks .this answers (and the other answers) are the solutions
My account is new so I can't upvote unfortunately

Comment: @Duyth you can mark answer as accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

bundles = {
    ("Product 1", "Product 2"): 12,
    ("Product 2", "Product 4"): 7,
    ("Product 3", "Product 1", "Product 5"): 6,
    ("Product 5",): 4,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{"product": f"Product {n}", "name": f"Name {n}"} for n in range(1, 6)]
)
```

```
pprint(bundles)
# {('Product 1', 'Product 2'): 12,
#  ('Product 2', 'Product 4'): 7,
#  ('Product 3', 'Product 1', 'Product 5'): 6,
#  ('Product 5',): 4}
```

```
pprint(df)
#      product    name
# 0  Product 1  Name 1
# 1  Product 2  Name 2
# 2  Product 3  Name 3
# 3  Product 4  Name 4
# 4  Product 5  Name 5
```

Possible solution:

```
# Allow using the "product" values as keys in the .loc below
df = df.set_index("product")

# Use a list comprehension to generate the keys of the new dict
# and another one to generate the dict using the names from df
bundles_by_name = {
    tuple(df.loc[prod, "name"] for prod in prods): bundles[prods] for prods in bundles
}
```

The result would look like this:

```
pprint(bundles_by_name)
# {('Name 1', 'Name 2'): 12,
#  ('Name 2', 'Name 4'): 7,
#  ('Name 3', 'Name 1', 'Name 5'): 6,
#  ('Name 5',): 4}
```

Comment: Yeah! :( I have also almost completed and I saw that :(

Comment: thanks guys
@xitiz Sorry about the trouble
I edited the post and took me 15 mins to realise my edit didn't go through. I'm gathering all the suggestions as the final goal is to still find out the product names - answered above). I'll give this a go and report back

Comment: for anyone who is after a solution to get just the product name, this works too . thanks @helder

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to transform the tuples into multiple rows, [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to join on your "map" of product IDs to names, and [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to "un-explode" the result:

```py
result = (
    df
    .explode('Key')
    .reset_index()
    .merge(id2name, left_on='Key', right_on='Product ID')
    .set_index('index')
    .assign(Product=z[['Key', 'Product Name']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg({'Product': list, 'Value': max})
)

>>> result
                                               Product  Value
row                                                          
0             [(Product1, Name 1), (Product2, Name 2)]     12
1             [(Product2, Name 2), (Product4, Name 4)]      7
2    [(Product1, Name 1), (Product3, Name 3), (Prod...      6
3                                 [(Product5, Name 5)]      4
```

The preamble used for a reproducible setup was:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Key': [
        ('Product1', 'Product2'),
        ('Product2', 'Product4'),
        ('Product3', 'Product1', 'Product5'),
        ('Product5',),        
    ], 'Value': [12, 7, 6, 4]
})

id2name = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product ID': [f'Product{i}' for i in range(6)],
    'Product Name': [f'Name {i}' for i in range(6)],
})
```

**Explanation**

Let's look at the various bits in that chained expression above.

First, explode the tuples into multiple rows, each with a single value:

```py
z = df.explode('Key')
>>> z
        Key  Value
0  Product1     12
0  Product2     12
1  Product2      7
1  Product4      7
2  Product3      6
2  Product1      6
2  Product5      6
3  Product5      4
```

Then, merge on `id2name`, but preserving the original index:

```
z = z.reset_index().merge(id2name, left_on='Key', right_on='Product ID').set_index('index')
>>> z
            Key  Value Product ID Product Name
index                                         
0      Product1     12   Product1       Name 1
2      Product1      6   Product1       Name 1
0      Product2     12   Product2       Name 2
1      Product2      7   Product2       Name 2
1      Product4      7   Product4       Name 4
2      Product3      6   Product3       Name 3
2      Product5      6   Product5       Name 5
3      Product5      4   Product5       Name 5
```

Then, make tuples from columns `'Product ID'` and `'Product Name'`:

```py
z = z.assign(Product=z[['Key', 'Product Name']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
>>> z
            Key  Value Product ID Product Name             Product
index                                                             
0      Product1     12   Product1       Name 1  (Product1, Name 1)
2      Product1      6   Product1       Name 1  (Product1, Name 1)
0      Product2     12   Product2       Name 2  (Product2, Name 2)
1      Product2      7   Product2       Name 2  (Product2, Name 2)
1      Product4      7   Product4       Name 4  (Product4, Name 4)
2      Product3      6   Product3       Name 3  (Product3, Name 3)
2      Product5      6   Product5       Name 5  (Product5, Name 5)
3      Product5      4   Product5       Name 5  (Product5, Name 5)
```

Finally, make lists again (un-explode) by grouping on the index (`level=0`):

```py
z = z.groupby(level=0).agg({'Product': list, 'Value': max})
>>> z
                                                 Product  Value
index                                                          
0               [(Product1, Name 1), (Product2, Name 2)]     12
1               [(Product2, Name 2), (Product4, Name 4)]      7
2      [(Product1, Name 1), (Product3, Name 3), (Prod...      6
3                                   [(Product5, Name 5)]      4
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-Pandas version (probably not the most efficient)

```
#input
#If only one product: add a comma after the product, otherwise Python will not recognize it as a tupple
d = {('Product1', 'Product2'):"12", ('Product2', 'Product4'):"7", ('Product3', 'Product1','Product5'):"6", ('Product5',):"4"} 
#Nested list for name references
l = [['Product1', 'Name1'],['Product2', 'Name2'],['Product3', 'Name3'],['Product4', 'Name4'],['Product5', 'Name5']] 
out = {}

for products in d: #Loop through each tuple of products in dictionary d
    t = []
    for product in products: #Loop through each product in the products tupple
        for names in l: #Loop through all names in the names list
            if product == names[0]:
                t.append(names[1]) #Append name to list
    out[tuple(t)] = int(d[products]) #Convert list to tupple and construct the dictionary
        
print(out)
```

Output for this example:

```
{('Name1', 'Name2'): 12, ('Name2', 'Name4'): 7, ('Name3', 'Name1', 'Name5'): 6, ('Name5',): 4}
```

Comment: you are right,  I didn't think about non Pandas version and this one looks really interesting. may dig around to see if I can have a large dataset to run with this